# Sort a numpy array by another array, along a particular axis

Tags: python, sorting, multidimensional-array, numpy

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903462/how-can-i-zip-sort-parallel-numpy-arrays/1903579#1903579), I have a pair of 3D numpy arrays, `a` and `b`, and I want to sort the entries of `b` by the values of `a`. Unlike [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903462/how-can-i-zip-sort-parallel-numpy-arrays/1903579#1903579), I want to sort only along one axis of the arrays.

My naive reading of the `numpy.argsort()` documentation:

```
Returns
-------
index_array : ndarray, int
    Array of indices that sort `a` along the specified axis.
    In other words, ``a[index_array]`` yields a sorted `a`.
```

led me to believe that I could do my sort with the following code:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.zeros((3, 3, 3))
a += numpy.array((1, 3, 2)).reshape((3, 1, 1))
print "a"
print a
"""
[[[ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]]

 [[ 3.  3.  3.]
  [ 3.  3.  3.]
  [ 3.  3.  3.]]

 [[ 2.  2.  2.]
  [ 2.  2.  2.]
  [ 2.  2.  2.]]]
"""
b = numpy.arange(3*3*3).reshape((3, 3, 3))
print "b"
print b
"""
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]]

 [[ 9 10 11]
  [12 13 14]
  [15 16 17]]

 [[18 19 20]
  [21 22 23]
  [24 25 26]]]
"""
print "a, sorted"
print numpy.sort(a, axis=0)
"""
[[[ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]]

 [[ 2.  2.  2.]
  [ 2.  2.  2.]
  [ 2.  2.  2.]]

 [[ 3.  3.  3.]
  [ 3.  3.  3.]
  [ 3.  3.  3.]]]
"""

##This isnt' working how I'd like
sort_indices = numpy.argsort(a, axis=0)
c = b[sort_indices]
"""
Desired output:

[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]]

 [[18 19 20]
  [21 22 23]
  [24 25 26]]

 [[ 9 10 11]
  [12 13 14]
  [15 16 17]]]
"""
print "Desired shape of b[sort_indices]: (3, 3, 3)."
print "Actual shape of b[sort_indices]:"
print c.shape
"""
(3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
"""
```

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You still have to supply indices for the other two dimensions for this to work correctly.

```
>>> a = numpy.zeros((3, 3, 3))
>>> a += numpy.array((1, 3, 2)).reshape((3, 1, 1))
>>> b = numpy.arange(3*3*3).reshape((3, 3, 3))
>>> sort_indices = numpy.argsort(a, axis=0)
>>> static_indices = numpy.indices((3, 3, 3))
>>> b[sort_indices, static_indices[1], static_indices[2]]
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
```

[`numpy.indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html#numpy.indices) calculates the indices of each axis of the array when "flattened" through the other two axes (or n - 1 axes where n = total number of axes). In other words, this (apologies for the long post):

```
>>> static_indices
array([[[[0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0]],

        [[1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1]],

        [[2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2],
         [2, 2, 2]]],


       [[[0, 0, 0],
         [1, 1, 1],
         [2, 2, 2]],

        [[0, 0, 0],
         [1, 1, 1],
         [2, 2, 2]],

        [[0, 0, 0],
         [1, 1, 1],
         [2, 2, 2]]],


       [[[0, 1, 2],
         [0, 1, 2],
         [0, 1, 2]],

        [[0, 1, 2],
         [0, 1, 2],
         [0, 1, 2]],

        [[0, 1, 2],
         [0, 1, 2],
         [0, 1, 2]]]])
```

These are the identity indices for each axis; when used to index b, they recreate b.

```
>>> b[static_indices[0], static_indices[1], static_indices[2]]
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

As an alternative to `numpy.indices`, you could use `numpy.ogrid`, as unutbu suggests. Since the object generated by `ogrid` is smaller, I'll create all three axes, just for consistency sake, but note unutbu's comment for a way to do this by generating only two.

```
>>> static_indices = numpy.ogrid[0:a.shape[0], 0:a.shape[1], 0:a.shape[2]]
>>> a[sort_indices, static_indices[1], static_indices[2]]
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.]],

       [[ 3.,  3.,  3.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  3.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  3.]]])
```

Comment: I like this answer. To save some memory, perhaps change `static_indices` to `static_indices = np.ogrid[0:a.shape[1],0:a.shape[2]]`. This will produce smaller arrays, but will do the same thing as `np.indices` by taking advantage of broadcasting. It could be used like this: `b[sort_indices, static_indices[1], static_indices[2]]`.

Comment: Err, `b[sort_indices, static_indices[0], static_indices[1]]` rather.

Comment: @unutbu, thanks! I'm still getting to know numpy's very rich indexing system; it's nice to know about an automatic way to generate broadcastable indices.

Answer (score 2):

[numpy.take_along_axis()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) does it, and presumably without unnecessary extra memory usage:

```
# From the original question:
import numpy
a = numpy.zeros((3, 3, 3))
a += numpy.array((1, 3, 2)).reshape((3, 1, 1))
b = numpy.arange(3*3*3).reshape((3, 3, 3))
sort_indices = numpy.argsort(a, axis=0)
# This is not working as expected:
c = b[sort_indices]
# This does what is expected:
c = numpy.take_along_axis(b, sort_indices, axis=0)
print(c)
"""
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]]

 [[18 19 20]
  [21 22 23]
  [24 25 26]]

 [[ 9 10 11]
  [12 13 14]
  [15 16 17]]]
"""
```

Comment: The answer should be more exhaustive and detailed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).