# Sort a numpy array by another array, along a particular axis, using less memory

Tags: python, sorting, multidimensional-array, numpy

From the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6155649/513688), I learned how to sort the entries of one numpy array `a` by the values of another numpy array `b`, along a particular axis.

However, this method requires the creation of several intermediate arrays that are the same size as `a`, one for each dimension of `a`. Some of my arrays are quite large, and this becomes inconvenient. Is there a way to accomplish the same goal that uses less memory?

Comment: Will the array `a` in the linked question always consist of blocks of equal numbers?  In this case, it would be rather easy to give a better solution.

Comment: Good question, Sven. In my real code, the array to be sorted is effectively random, I just gave a fairly trivial example for illustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a record array serve your purposes?

```
>>> a = numpy.zeros((3, 3, 3))
>>> a += numpy.array((1, 3, 2)).reshape((3, 1, 1))
>>> b = numpy.arange(3*3*3).reshape((3, 3, 3))
>>> c = numpy.array(zip(a.flatten(), b.flatten()), dtype=[('f', float), ('i', int)]).reshape(3, 3, 3)
>>> c.sort(axis=0)
>>> c['i']
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
```

A cleaner way to generate the coupled array:

```
>>> c = numpy.rec.fromarrays([a, b], dtype=[('f', float), ('i', int)])
```

or

```
>>> c = numpy.rec.fromarrays([a, b], names='f, i')
```

Comment: I should add that this is very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903462/how-can-i-zip-sort-parallel-numpy-arrays) but since that one doesn't address multidimensional arrays explicitly, I think it's worth having a separate question.

Comment: Neat, I didn't know about record arrays. I'll try this out.

Comment: The record array approach was exactly what I was looking for. Great answer.

Comment: It's great that you can specify which field of the record array to sort by with the 'order' keyword argument, too.