# Sort N-D numpy array by another 1-D array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

From the answer to this question ([Sort a numpy array by another array, along a particular axis, using less memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162172/sort-a-numpy-array-by-another-array-along-a-particular-axis-using-less-memory)), I learned how to sort a multidimensional numpy array `a` by the values of another numpy array `b` without creating too many additional arrays.

However, `numpy.rec.fromarrays([a, b])` only works if the arrays `a` and `b` have the same shape. My `b` array is 1-D array, but `a` array is a N-D array (N is not specified). Is it a nice way (and efficient) to sort the `a` array among a particular axis by the value of the 1-D array `b`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.take` with the `axis` keyword argument:

```
>>> a = np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2, 3, 4)
>>> a
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
>>> b = np.arange(3)
>>> np.random.shuffle(b)
>>> b
array([1, 0, 2])
>>> np.take(a, b, axis=1)
array([[[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19],
        [12, 13, 14, 15],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

If you want to use fancy indexing, you just need to pad the indexing tuple with enough empty slices:

```
>>> a[:, b]
array([[[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19],
        [12, 13, 14, 15],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

Or in a more general setting:

```
>>> axis = 1
>>> idx = (slice(None),) * axis + (b,)
>>> a[idx]
array([[[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19],
        [12, 13, 14, 15],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

But `np.take` should really be your first option.