# Sort N-D numpy array by column with a smaller N-D array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I understand that through [Sort N-D numpy array by another 1-D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058249/sort-n-d-numpy-array-by-another-1-d-array) the use of fancy indexing, I can do the following `c = a[:, :, b]` with `b` defining the order to which I want to sort by column

```
>>> a = np.array([[[ 0,  1], [ 2,  3]],
                  [[ 4,  5], [ 6,  7]],
                  [[ 8,  9], [10, 11]]])
>>> b = np.array([1, 0])
>>> c = a[:, :, b]
>>> c
array([[[ 1,  0],
        [ 3,  2]],

       [[ 5,  4],
        [ 7,  6]],

       [[ 9,  8],
        [11, 10]]])
```

Now I increase `b` with 2 more inputs to `b2` corresponding to how I want to sort each set of 2x2 in `a`

```
>>> b2 = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]])
>>> c2 = ?
>>> c2
array([[[ 1,  0],
        [ 3,  2]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 9,  8],
        [11, 10]]])
```

I have a larger set of inputs and I have a function that returns an array similar to 'b2' which provides me the info to which I should obtain. Hence may I know what should I filling into the `c2 = ?` in order to get the desired result?

Comment: Shouldn't `b2` be `np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]])` (last row swapped) for that expected output?

Comment: @ajcr Thanks for spotting that mistake! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one approach with *fancy-indexing* -

```
(a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None],:,b2]).transpose(0,2,1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [191]: a
Out[191]: 
array([[[7, 8, 5, 2, 0],
        [6, 7, 0, 7, 1],
        [7, 6, 5, 4, 0]],

       [[8, 0, 5, 5, 7],
        [4, 3, 4, 0, 1],
        [8, 6, 3, 2, 4]],

       [[3, 2, 7, 3, 7],
        [4, 3, 0, 1, 5],
        [4, 3, 7, 8, 7]]])

In [192]: b2
Out[192]: 
array([[1, 2, 4, 3, 0],
       [4, 2, 0, 1, 3],
       [1, 3, 4, 0, 2]])

In [193]: (a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None],:,b2]).transpose(0,2,1)
Out[193]: 
array([[[8, 5, 0, 2, 7],
        [7, 0, 1, 7, 6],
        [6, 5, 0, 4, 7]],

       [[7, 5, 8, 0, 5],
        [1, 4, 4, 3, 0],
        [4, 3, 8, 6, 2]],

       [[2, 3, 7, 3, 7],
        [3, 1, 5, 4, 0],
        [3, 8, 7, 4, 7]]])
```

Comment: This is a nice example of [mixing advanced and basic indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing).

Comment: @unutbu And I didn't even know that I was mixing things up! :)

Answer (score 1):

In case nobody finds a pure fancy-indexing solution, this here is one that loops through the first axis:

```
np.asarray([a[n,:,p] for n,p in enumerate(b2)])

array([[[ 1,  3],
    [ 0,  2]],

   [[ 4,  6],
    [ 5,  7]],

   [[ 9, 11],
    [ 8, 10]]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A fancy-indexing solution will be better bcos speed is what I'm looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to `@Divakar's` solution but without the `transpose`.

```
In [259]: I,J, K = np.ogrid[:3,:2,:2]

In [260]: a[I, J, b[:,None,:]]
Out[260]: 
array([[[ 1,  0],
        [ 3,  2]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 9,  8],
        [11, 10]]])
```

I'm using `ogrid` (or `np.ix_`) as a compact way of generating 2 3d arrays that broadcast with `b[:,None,:]` to produce a set of `(3,2,2)` indices.

The equivalent with full `Nones` is:

```
a[np.arange(3)[:,None,None], np.arange(2)[None,:,None], b[:,None,:]]
```

(this makes it clearer that `b` is selecting items along the 1st and last axes)

To see the full broadcasted indexing arrays, print:

```
 np.broadcast_arrays(I,J,b[:,None,:])
```

Comment: Thanks! Similar to Divakar's answer, I learnt a lot and thanks for also explaining it step by step.