# Combine two lists and then sort each column

Tags: python

I have a file [ Name Age Marks] . I have stored each values of  Name in a list1 . Marks in list2. I have combined both lists using zip function in python:

```
 list3 =[]
 list3 = zip(list1,list2)
```

Eg:
list3 = ((Steve,32),(David,65),(Ram,43),(Mary,87))
Now I want to sort list3 in descending order of marks. So kindly help how to proceed with this. I am new to python.
Thanks for your time and consideration. Awaiting response

Comment: Variable names should be descriptive. Instead of `list1`, why not `names`? And instead of `list2`, why not `marks`?

Comment: You don't need to do `list3 =[]` before assigning it to `zip`, by the way. I'm guessing you're doing it in order to "declare" that `list3` is a list. But in Python, variables do not need declaration; you could have done `list3 = 2342` instead, and everything would still work the same way. So you may as well not put anything before `list3 = zip(...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I "zip sort" parallel numpy arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903462/how-can-i-zip-sort-parallel-numpy-arrays)

Answer (score 2):

[`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) accept optional `key` function. Return values of the function are used for comparison.

```
>>> list3 = [('Steve',32),('David',65),('Ram',43),('Mary',87)]
>>> sorted(list3, key=lambda item: item[1])
[('Steve', 32), ('Ram', 43), ('David', 65), ('Mary', 87)]

>>> sorted(list3, key=lambda item: -item[1]) # negate the return value.
[('Mary', 87), ('David', 65), ('Ram', 43), ('Steve', 32)]

>>> sorted(list3, key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True) # using `reverse`
[('Mary', 87), ('David', 65), ('Ram', 43), ('Steve', 32)]
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I would like to know if I have a list :