# Line chart Of two Numpy arrays matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, linear-regression

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x_test,y_pred)
print(x_test)
print()
print(y_pred)
print()
print(y_test)
plt.plot(x_test,y_test)
plt.show()
```

I'm trying to plot a line chart using above 3 arrays all the arrays are of same shape but still for some reason the line chart is coming out to be messy. I'm still a noob could anyone please tell me the mistake?

**Output:**

```
 [31.588117   53.66093226 46.68222865 43.10782022 70.34607562 44.49285588
 57.5045333  36.93007661 55.80573336 38.95476907 56.9012147  56.86890066
 34.3331247  59.04974121 57.78822399 54.28232871 51.0887199  50.28283635
 44.21174175 38.00548801 32.94047994 53.69163957 68.76573427 46.2309665
 68.31936082 50.03017434 49.23976534 50.03957594 48.14985889 25.12848465]

[ 48.07285783  77.96480957  68.51395026  63.67333329 100.56054527
  65.5490079   83.16997871  55.30716832  80.86939107  58.04909356
  82.35293882  82.30917777  51.79026483  85.26256544  83.55416479
  78.80633125  74.48140943  73.39004741  65.1683111   56.76353649
  49.90428565  78.00639472  98.42037934  67.90283173  97.8158813
  73.0478817   71.97747598  73.06061375  70.50147799  39.32494706]

[ 50.39267014  63.64239878  72.24725107  57.81251298 104.25710159
  86.64202032  91.486778    55.23166089  79.55043668  44.84712424
  80.20752314  83.14274979  55.72348926  77.63418251  99.05141484
  79.12064627  69.58889785  69.51050331  73.68756432  61.36690454
  67.17065577  85.66820315 114.85387123  90.12357207  97.91982104
  81.53699078  72.11183247  85.23200734  66.22495789  53.45439421]
```

[image]

Comment: it's drawing the line in the order of the array, so since your x-axis goes from 31, to 53, and back to 46, you'll see the orange line do exactly that.  Since there is no order to your data, I would suggest using a scatterplot.

Comment: As an alternative to what Chris suggests, if you're really attached to a line chart, you can sort all of your arrays using keys from the array you're using for your x values.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67020841/4365003

Comment: Using a line plot for non-temporal data is probably a bad design choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your x-axis is not sorted, the line will be messy. It plots exactly what you tell it to the plot. If you want a line graph, you'll need to sort your data first (while making sure your other vectors are sorted accordingly). You can easily do that with Pandas, for example.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x_test': x_test,
                   'y_test': y_test,
                   'y_pred': y_pred})

df.sort_values('x_test', inplace=True)

plt.plot(df.x_test, df.y_pred)
plt.plot(df.x_test, df.y_test)
plt.show()
```

[image: lineplot result]

Alternatively, as mentioned before, you're probably better of with a scatter plot:

```py
plt.figure()
plt.plot(df.x_test, df.y_pred)
plt.scatter(df.x_test, df.y_test)
plt.show()
```

[image: scatterplot result]